# Problem with google map location in React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-maps

I create an MERN stack app and I want to add button for opening a new page to choose location like address and this adress is for delivery order. I create MapScreen.js and I added marker , which show my choosing place in the map in the code, but the problem is when I open the screen in browser , it show me message "Google map don't loading right" and I don't see the marker. And another problem is when I choose one location , the LAT and LNG values don't change. They stay in default values. I show the code :

**MapScreen.js**

```
   import axios from 'axios';
    import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
    import {
      LoadScript,
      GoogleMap,
      StandaloneSearchBox,
      Marker,
    } from '@react-google-maps/api';
    import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Store } from '../Store';
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
    import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
    
    const defaultLocation = { lat: 45.516, lng: -73.56 };
    const libs = ['places'];
    
    
    export default function MapScreen() {
      const { state, dispatch: ctxDispatch } = useContext(Store);
      const { userInfo } = state;
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      const [googleApiKey, setGoogleApiKey] = useState('');
      const [center, setCenter] = useState(defaultLocation);
      const [location, setLocation] = useState(center);
    
      const mapRef = useRef(null);
      const placeRef = useRef(null);
      const markerRef = useRef(null);
    
      const getUserCurrentLocation = () => {
        if (!navigator.geolocation) {
          alert('Geolocation os not supported by this browser');
        } else {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            setCenter({
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude,
            });
            setLocation({
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude,
            });
          });
        }
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetch = async () => {
          const { data } = await axios('/api/keys/google', {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
          });
          setGoogleApiKey(data.key);
          getUserCurrentLocation();
        };
    
        fetch();
        ctxDispatch({
          type: 'SET_FULLBOX_ON',
        });
      }, [ctxDispatch, userInfo]);
    
      const onLoad = (map) => {
        mapRef.current = map;
      };
      const onIdle = () => {
        setLocation({
          lat: mapRef.current.center.lat(),
          lng: mapRef.current.center.lng(),
        });
      };
    
      const onLoadPlaces = (place) => {
        placeRef.current = place;
      };
      const onPlacesChanged = () => {
        const place = placeRef.current.getPlaces()[0].geometry.location;
        setCenter({ lat: place.lat(), lng: place.lng() });
        setLocation({ lat: place.lat(), lng: place.lng() });
      };
    
      const onMarkerLoad = (marker) => {
        markerRef.current = marker;
      };
    
      const onConfirm = () => {
        const places = placeRef.current.getPlaces() || [{}];
        ctxDispatch({
          type: 'CAR_ADDRESS_MAP_LOCATION',
          payload: {
            lat: location.lat,
            lng: location.lng,
            address: places[0].formatted_address,
            name: places[0].name,
            vicinity: places[0].vicinity,
            googleAddressId: places[0].id,
          },
        });
        toast.success('location selected successfully.');
        navigate('/personaldata');
      };
      return (
        <div className="full-box">
          <LoadScript libraries={libs} googleMapsApiKey={googleApiKey}>
            <GoogleMap
              id="samaple-map"
              mapContainerStyle={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
              center={center}
              zoom={15}
              onLoad={onLoad}
              onIdle={onIdle}
            >
              <StandaloneSearchBox
                onLoad={onLoadPlaces}
                onPlacesChanged={onPlacesChanged}
              >
                <div className="map-input-box">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your address"></input>
                  <Button type="button" onClick={onConfirm}>
                    Confirm
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </StandaloneSearchBox>
              <Marker position={location} onLoad={onMarkerLoad}></Marker>
            </GoogleMap>
          </LoadScript>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Did you make sure that you allowed location tracking in your browser? Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like a codesandbox? That would greatly help.